# Does DirectX9 support 64 / 128 bit color depth formats?

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl, slimdx

Does DirectX support 64 bit color depth formats? Such as Format.A16R16G16B16. I have some code that uses this format and it compiles but I does not seem to work. Note: I know my display can't show 64bit color the texture is for getting more color info into a pixel shader. If we are intrested in my motivation for this question please see these links.

[Why is this 128Bit Color Format being converted to 32Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839758/why-is-this-128bit-color-format-being-converted-to-32bit)

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/632620-why-is-this-128bit-color-format-being-converted-to-32bit-hlslslimdx-9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does support 64-bit and 128-bit colour modes.  Whether your graphics card supports it or not is a different matter, however.

You ***may*** need to use a ps_2_a/ps_2_b or ps_3_0 profile though.

Comment: Yeah I think I figured out my problem. I was trying to us DrawString to render to a 64 bit color deep target but I think the DrawString uses a 32bit surface to render each char causing a loss in data. I am going to have to fix this.